# Using Elasticsearch, how do I do a filtered query on both my document properties and nested document properties?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is an example document source.

```
{
     "tags": [
         "meow",
         "cats",
         "feline"
    ],
    "visible": 1,
    "for_sale": "y",
    "title": "Cat Meow",
    "stock": [{
        "department": "mens",
        "size": "small"
    }, {
        "department": "mens",
        "size": "medium"
    }]
}
```

I want to find documents that are 'stock.department=mens' and 'stock.size=medium' and also are 'for_sale=y'

Here is the query that I've come up with so far. I can't figure out how to filter by for_sale=y.

```
{
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["title", "tags"],
                    "query": "cat"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "stock",
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "stock.size": "medium"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term": {
                                    "stock.department": "mens"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with. If anyone has any critiques or improvements please share them.

```
{
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["title", "tags"],
                    "query": "cat"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "for_sale": "y"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "visible": 1
                        }
                    }, {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "stock",
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                        "term": {
                                            "stock.size": "medium"
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        "term": {
                                            "stock.department": "mens"
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```